# sqlalchemy Error creating backref on relationship: property of that name exists on mapper

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two very simple models. In my `Post` model there are supposed to be two relationships into the `User` table. One is for the owner of the post and one is for the last editor of the post. They can be different values, but both refer to the same `User` table.

My models are set up like this

```
class Post(Base):
    last_editor_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=True)
    last_editor = relationship('User', backref='posts', foreign_keys=[last_editor_id])
    owner_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    owner = relationship('User', backref='posts', foreign_keys=[owner_id])
    
class User(Base):
    '''This represents a user on the site'''
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False)
```

When I attempt to create these models though, I get the following error

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'posts' on relationship 'Post.owner': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper|User|users'

How do I correct this so that I can maintain both foreign keys in the `Post` model?

Comment: Note: Since SQLAlchemy 2.0, `backref` is considered [legacy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/backref.html#relationships-backref); `back_populates` is preferred.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The error is telling you that you've used `post` as a name more then once for your backrefs, all you need to do is give the backref's unique names.  Here's a complete example-- I've added a id primary key to the Post class, and also some `__repr__`s so we get some readable output.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, BigInteger, ForeignKey, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite://') ## In Memory.
Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
session = Session()

class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    last_editor_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=True)
    last_editor = relationship('User', backref='editor_posts', foreign_keys=[last_editor_id])
    owner_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    owner = relationship('User', backref='owner_posts', foreign_keys=[owner_id])

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post: {}>'.format(self.id)


class User(Base):
    '''This represents a user on the site'''
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User: {}>'.format(self.name)



Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

bob = User(name='Bob', id=1)
alice = User(name='Alice', id=2)
post = Post(owner=alice, last_editor=bob, id=1)

session.add(post)
session.commit()

bob = session.query(User).get(1)
print(bob)
# <User: Bob>
print(bob.editor_posts)
# [<Post: 1>]
print(bob.owner_posts)
# []

post = session.query(Post).get(1)
print(post.owner)
# <User: Alice>
print(post.last_editor)
# <User: Bob>
```

Now when you query a user, you can ask that object `user.owner_posts` or `user.editor_posts`.

Comment: Still works when using Python 3.11 and SqlAlchemy 2 (once the print statments are updated). Thanks, I looked for a long time for an example like this.

Answer (score 6):

In general it's a naming Problem of the backref.

Since 1:n relationships are sometimes a bit confusing, I set the relationship attribute
always on the singular site, to avoid confusion.

then the backref name is always singular. and the relationship attribute is always in the Class where the foreignkey is referencing to.

Now to my suggestion for the fixed code:

```
class Post(Base):
    last_editor_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=True)

    owner_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False, index=True)


class User(Base):
    '''This represents a user on the site'''
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False)
    owned_posts = relationship('Post', backref='owner')
    edited_posts = relationship('Post', backref='last_editor')
```

Now you can get all the owned posts of a `User` with `User.owned_posts` and all owners of a post with `Post.owner`. Same with the last_edited attribute.

For additional info you could read the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html) how to set up relationships

Comment: "Also this shouldn't result in a working relationship, since your relationshipreference have to be in the class you are reffering to and not in the ones with the Foreignkey" is wrong.  I've expanded my example in the other answer to show it working.

Answer (score 0):

##### You can correct the error and maintain both foreign keys in the `Post` model using unique `backref` names

###### The correct code would be this

```py
class Post(Base):
    last_editor_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=True)
    last_editor = relationship('User', backref='edited_posts', foreign_keys=[last_editor_id])
    owner_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    owner = relationship('User', backref='owned_posts', foreign_keys=[owner_id])

class User(Base):
    '''This represents a user on the site'''
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False)
```

##### Why

1. `backref` automatically creates a relationship on the User side, but it's less explicit and can lead to confusion in complex scenarios.

I changed the `backref` names to `'edited_posts'` for the `last_editor` relationship and `'owned_posts'` for the owner relationship.

Now, when you access the posts of a user, you can use `user.edited_posts` for posts edited by the user and `user.owned_posts` for posts owned by the user.